# Speed up updates in SQL Server for billions of records?

Tags: sql-server

I want to update billions of records in SQL Server 2008 and later. I don't want the database to be slowed down or locked.

The column I want to update is a column storing a date as `nvarchar` datatype that I want to change from 8 digits to ten.

Which is the best speed?

Comment: Is a production/live database?

Comment: A `DATE` column doesn't have any "digits" - it's stored in a binary format internally, and formatted for display according to your settings. Not really clear what you're trying to do here......

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  its live database- some users are using it.

Comment: Some things which might speed up the update would be to disable all indices and unique constraints.  But, you could only even consider this if you took down the site for some time.

Comment: @marc_s we save that dates as nvarchar

Comment: Do you mean you want to alter the column, or just change the values inside? Perhaps both?

Comment: **Don't do that!** Seriously - if it's a **date** - store it as a `DATE` datatype! Don't mishandle dates by storing them as strings.....

Comment: @ZoharPeled  just  i want  change the values inside

Comment: @marc_s this dates stored in data base from 10 years ago until now-

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Comment: @marc_s i cant change type of column in database now-its live db and have a lot of sp and query

Comment: You should change the column's data type. Frankly, I'm surprised this database lasted 10 years without this change. Date values do not belong in an `nvarchar` column.  Since this is a live database you should start by mapping the columns dependents objects and plan your work for a minimum down-time. This can be done by using a copy to create the relevant SQL scripts and dry-run it a couple of times to make sure everything is working fine, and then on the live db all you have to do is a minimum down-time that will only be for the time it takes to run the scripts.

Comment: @marc_s
@ZoharPeled@tim
  every body!
please answer to my main question-it not matter whats the type of my column-
you can think its not nvarchar!
how can i update billions columns faster?

Comment: Update in bulks to prevent a full table lock. Try bulk sizes from 10,000 to 100,000 to see what gives you the best results.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: any transaction in SQL Server with over **5'000** locks (for update) will cause a lock escalation to exclusive table lock - batches therefore need to be 5000 rows or less to avoid table locks

Comment: @ZoharPeled tanx!
have best regard!

Comment: @ZoharPeled
whats your idea about that i create new column and then insert new value to that new column by 10000to100000
after its done,rename the column name?

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the info! It's been a long time since I've needed to use bulk update so I couldn't remember the numbers.

Comment: Steps to modify data type: 1. Switch to downtime mode. 2. Backup 3. Create a new column with the desired type. 4. Use an `update` statement to populate it with the data converted from the wrong data type. Use `try_cast` or `try_convert` to leave it null when data is malformed.  5. Try to populate any values they where left as null (manually check the data - if lucky, you can use another `update` with `try_convert` and a different style. 6. Drop old column. 5. Rename new column to the name the old column used to have. 7. Change dependent objects (if needed) to work with the proper data type.